# How to activate an OSGI bundle only when the certain condition is satisfied?

Tags: java, reference, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm a bit new in OSGI and I want the following: to activate my bundle only when some prerequisites are satisfied (which, btw, we get form a native library, but that's another story). AFAIK it could be achieved through the @Reference DS, but I don't get the idea fully. I mean if I write something like this before my @Activate DS:

```
@Reference
public AnotherService as

@Activate
public void activate() {
   //some code 
}
```

this actually means, that my bundle won't be activated until the AnotherService is activated. But could I write in `AnotherService` or in my bundle something like this?:

```
@Activate
public void activate() {
   if (condition){
       deactivate()
   }
   //some code 
}

@Deactivate
public void deactivate() {
//some code
}
```

As far as I understand, that's impossible. Then the questions arises: how could I control the activation of my bundle or its references depending on certain condition(s)? I.e. I want my bundle to be either activated, when the condition is satisfied (**before activation**) or deactivated, when not. It won't suit for me the way: "just make if-statement, if it is not satisfied, do nothing, but still be activated", because the 'activiy' of this bundle is very resource heavy. Maybe I just have a fully wrong idea of OSGI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you should do. Your bundle should always be activated as long as it can be resolved (i.e. all of its imports and other static dependencies are satisfied).

In fact, unless you are coding OSGi at an advanced level, you should not write BundleActivators at all. If you are reading an OSGi tutorial in 2020 that tells you to write a BundleActivator, stop reading... that tutorial is junk.

You should use Declarative Services components. A component is an object managed by OSGi and can have its lifecycle bound to the availability of a service. For example:

```java
@Component
public class MyComponent implements MyService {

  private final AnotherService service;

  @Activate
  public MyComponent(@Reference AnotherService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In this example, an instance of `MyComponent` will be created and published as a service of type `MyService` **only** when a service of type `AnotherService` is available. You will be able to invoke the `AnotherService` via the final `service` field. This is a mandatory service reference, which is the default in DS, but it's also possible to create optional and dynamic references (i.e. references that can re-bind to other service instances during the lifetime of your component), but don't worry about those use-cases until later in your OSGi learning.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I used @Component DS for sure as well, just didn't write about this in the main post. But my question could be reformulated in a following way: how could I make `AnotherService` available  **only** when certain condition is satisfied? What is implicitly meant by this "when the service is avaialble"? I got it in a way, that it means that this service is simply activated. That's why I asked about the possibility of controlling this activation depending on some conditions.

Comment: It depends what kind of condition you are talking about. You'll see from my example above, `MyService` shall only be available when a condition is satisfied: that condition is the availability of `AnotherService`. Other kinds of conditions may require other techniques.

Comment: Ok, I will specify it a bit.

I have a C++ dll, which is loaded via JNA and which functions are called in this bundle (i.e. an interface object on the java side is created and manipulated). I have a DLL checking policy, which checks, whether the additional dlls are of precisely required versions (this is all done on the C++ side). I could call this check in java as a boolean method of my interface. Now, what I want - I want my bundle to be activated only if this boolean method returns true. Otherwise I don't want to activate this bundle. How could I implement this in OSGI?

Comment: Again, don't conditionally activate bundles. Work at the higher level. Represent your C++ functions as services. If the DLL version checks pass, then programmatically register a service in OSGi using the `BundleContext.registerService` method. Then you can bind your DS components to the availability of that service.

Comment: Thanks, that what I was looking for.